# mysql max_user_connections bot traffic

Tags: mysql, perl

Every month or two a swarm of robot visits my site and opens up connections so fast that my current max_user_connection value of 25 (will increase it to 75) is reached. Currently I restart the server and it works fine again until the next swarm comes. It is a webshop programmed in perl which tries to get the data using DBI connect.

So I have some questions :
Will the problem solve itself after some time or will the open process run until reset and try to get infos from the locked DB ?
Is it possible to do a small query to check for max user connections on the DB to exit if it is to high ?
Any other idea to get protection from DOS attacks or bot swarms (thought about rectriciting Asian IPs in htaccess) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can detect ( for example robots ) with a module. For example [HTTP::BrowserDetect](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aBrowserDetect).

```
use HTTP::BrowserDetect;

my $browser = HTTP::BrowserDetect->new($user_agent_string);
if ( $browser->robot() ) {
   # dont open an mysql connection, 
   # return a cached version of the requested page
   # or something like that
   ...
}
```

Comment: I'm the maintainer of HTTP::BrowserDetect. This is a very good use case for this module.